# Smart Array P400 battery failure

Tags: hp, hp-smart-array, controller

The P400 Smart Array controller in my HP DL380G5 is indicating:

`Battery Status: Failed, Replace Battery 1`

in the System Management Homepage. Also the IML indicates:

`POST Error: 1794-Drive Array - Array Accelerator Battery Charge Low`

I do have several replacement batteries (actually, several controllers including batteries) lying around at work but never had to actually replace one. I am wondering if the battery replacement (swap) could be done **hot** or if I need to take down my server to do the battery replacement.

I have replaced other spare parts like fans and drives before and all those can be replaced hot. I just don't know about the battery of the P400 Smart Array controller. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT1**

For those interested: [straight from the horse's mouth](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00572169/c00572169.pdf):

[image: Relevant quote from the manual]

With thanks to Frands Hansen pointing it out [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/428951/smart-array-p400-battery-failure#comment459233_428953).

**EDIT2**

In the end I did just power down, to be on the safe side and because the manual says so, and replace the battery. Couldn't be easier. Unplugged the old one of the end of the cable (not the end connected to the controller) and reconnected a spare one. The replaced battery is now in the server for about an hour and currently (still) recharging. I'm assuming all will end wel.

Comment: Power the server down first- I replace these all the time.
http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c00300504

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To give you a short, precise and correct anwer: no.

While I have not personally swapped any of them, I have watched our hardware techs do it dozens of times.

It requires the server to be shut down, then the battery can be swapped and the server can be booted again.

### From the P400 manual:

[image]

Comment: `"To give you a short, precise and correct anwer: no."` I didn't expect any longer than that :P Thanks for the reply. Now I know. So now I can start planning downtime for that machine. Thanks! I will accept as answer as soon as serverfault.com lets me :P

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to mark if you believe that your question has been answered. It makes it way easier for you to have people make an effort to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: As I mentioned (in my edit, just before you wrote this comment): I will accept as soon as serverfault lets me: `You can accept an answer in 5 minutes`

Comment: And I just noticed now that you do know your way around the system (stack exchange score) - sorry for trying to teach you a lesson, he he.

Comment: I just got an exact opposite answer from [ewwhite](http://serverfault.com/a/428953/116533). I guess I'll have to wait a little longer before accepting :P If it's you vs. him I'll just take my chances tomorrow and try it hot. What could go wrong, right? :D I'll post the outcome: server went up in smoke or everything went fine :P

Comment: Accepted the answer and editted my question to include a screenshot of the page(s) you referred to. Then I noticed you (or gWaldo) editted in a "quote" from the manual also. Mine was providing a little bit more context though so I'll leave it in the question. Thanks again, both!